# How to put MySQL 8.0 (X DevAPI) table data into a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, datagrid

I'm unable to figure out how to bind the **MySQL Table Data** (from the new `X DevAPI, MySQL 8.0`) into the **WPF DataGrid** by using the old way. Specifically, the `MySqlDataAdapter` then filling the `DataTable` to display in the `DataGrid`.

I have been trying to follow the documentation linked [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/devapi-users-working-with-relational-tables.html) in order to somehow use select. But to no avail, I'm unable to do so.

I've also tried using the `MySqlDataAdapter` anyway, but it only outputted this:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unsupported protocol version.'

Comment: Is your server listening to both ports 3306 and 33060?

Comment: @DaveStokes Yes, but the problem is more of like in the code side rather than the connection itself